# Entity Framework not all detecting changes on model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

**Background**

I have code in an overridden `SaveChanges` method which finds modified or new objects and creates a hash for the object but here I'm having difficulty picking up that a certain object has changed.

**Code**

I've managed to distill the issue (although this may just be the correct behavior) down to these lines.

Code in relevant method:

```
db.SaveChanges(); //for sake of easy example, ensure no other changes need to be saved
Models.File file1 = db.ImportFiles.Find(FileId);
file1.FileData = new FileData();
db.SaveChanges(); //run SaveChanges override which has custom code for hashing content
```

---

Main chunk of code in overridden `SaveChanges()`:

```
public override int SaveChanges(){
    var updates = ChangeTracker.Entries().ToList();
    var updateHashQueue = new List<DbEntityEntry>();
    foreach (DbEntityEntry entry in updates.Where(x => (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified)))
    {
        updateHashQueue.Add(entry); //only the FileData object shows here, never the File object
    }
    base.SaveChanges(); //Later hashing needs IDs to exist
    HashObjects(updateHashQueue); //takes relevant objects to create hashes (these objects have a "Hash" field)
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Explanation**

Having changed a model of type `File` by having it contain an instance of `FileData`, Entity Framework's `ChangeTracker.Entries()` contains both the `FileData` object and the `File` object, but only the former is in an `EntityState.Modified` state while the `File` object is showing as `EntityState.Unchanged`.

I'm thinking the answer for this may just be that this is exactly how it's meant to work but I'm wondering if there is a way to generically pick up that models, like the `File` one in this example, have changed in this way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the overridden code for `SaveChanges()` as this may be where the problem lies.

Comment: Hi Kieran, thanks for the advice. I've added some extra context to the latter part of `SaveChanges` but the main part where I'm not getting the desired outcome seems to be the in `ChangeTracker.Entries` with the `Unchanged` state of the `File` object.

Comment: The `File` object will never be anything other than unchanged because it doesn't exist in the database yet.

Comment: But I'm pulling an existing file when I run `db.ImportFiles.Find(FileId);`, no?

Comment: Sorry, I got mixed up between `File` and `FileData`.

Comment: Is the database a purely code first scaffold or did it already exist and you have created them manually? I'm thinking that if the DB already existed and you have created the DB entities by hand, then there may be missing relationship information that the change tracker needs.

Comment: In this case it's Code-First. The property is defined as such `public virtual FileData File { get; set; }`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you just have to call:

```
db.SaveChanges();
Models.File file1 = db.ImportFiles.Find(FileId);
db.ImportFiles.Update(file1); //Added line
file1.FileData = new FileData();
db.SaveChanges();
```

This will tell entityframework that you want the changetracker to begin tracking that entities state.

Comment: I think the issue is more to do with why EF change tracker isn't automatically picking up the state change as it should do.

Comment: hmm i don't think navigation properties are tracked by default, you either track them manually by calling Update() as described or (maybe not sure about this) if you use the include syntax from ef core.

so something like:
db.ImportFiles.Where(x => x.FileId == FileId)
.Include(x => x.FileData)
.FirstOrDefault();

Comment: EF & EF Core should both track all navigation properties by default. https://dotnetfiddle.net/3yiEUX

Comment: I think i understand the problem now... 
in your fiddle the Customer Entity would also not show up as modified in the changetracker.
That's because you are not modifying an entity but adding a completly new one.
If you want it in the modified state you will have to call Update.
(in your fiddle is a minor error, it should be dump(list2) and you would see that it is a completly new entity.

Comment: No one said that the child entity should be tracked, the issue that @Geesh_SO is having is that the parent record isn't being updated when the navigation property is set. Also in my example, the list output is the same.